# Git: get all non-pushed branches

Tags: git

There is a number of the branches in my project repository. 
And I was working on those during the years. Of course, I had to be accurate and should remove completed local branches (which reflect corresponding jira tickets), but sadly I did this not always.

Current scenario requires to migrate to another dev desktop, 
potentially I could push all local branches to the remote and clone/pull from new host. however I can't forcely push them , I need to initially get the list of non pushed branches, manually review them and decide to push them or not.

How to get the list of non-synchronized local branches ? I could not find such commend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something along the lines of

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(if:notequals==)%(upstream:trackshort)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' refs/heads | sort -u
```

which uses `for-each-ref`'s very handy `%(if)%(then)[%(else)]%(end)` construct to filter upon upstream track status.

The final `| sort -u` is just presentation bonus, mostly to strip blank lines.

---

However, I realize there's still a slight inaccuracy here : it'll output the list of branches **not in sync** with their remote counterpart, yes, but branches ahead **or** behind will be displayed, while I guess you only wanted those *ahead*. It might be a non-problem in your context, but be aware of it.